# Directory.Create return false positive

Tags: c#, io

We have an application that sometime return false positive on both `Directory.Exist()` and `Directory.CreateDirectory()` and it happen at random.

First the folder is a shared folder on a test computer with full right to everyone, firewall disable and no anti virus installed. That computer is running on `Windows Server 2008` and no software are installed. The shared folder has caching disabled to not allow offline mode. The folder path in this case is `\\TestComputer\data\`

In the application we do :

```
// this in a loop with the 100-200 folders to create
CreateData(@"\\TestComputer\data\folder1\");


private void CreateData(string path)
{
    try
    {
        var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        if(dir == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("path did not create properly");
        }
        else
        {
            if(Directory.Exist(path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("path exist");

                CreateFiles(path);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("path does not exist");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("an error occured");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that we sometime get the "path exist" while the folder is not created and so does not exist. So what this mean is that the `Directory.CreateDirectory()` does return a non-null object and on top of that `Directory.Exist()` also return true. This is a false result.

Server that has the shared folder and the PC using the application both has show hidden files and system file and the folder is not there. We know because the next method after that sample code saves a file in that folder and it fails with an error saying that the folder doesn't exist (which is true).

We already verified all Virtual store on the Server and on the PC running the code above and the folders are totally empty.

This code can run for hundreds and hundreds of folder (obviously the path in the sample code is an actual parameter that changes) and once in a while it will tell me the folder is created and it will say that the folder exist see a folder that does not exist.

All folders we create contain only standard letters without accent so a to z and A to Z, numbers and 1 or 2 dash so nothing fancy.

Comment: Is it possible that some other thread or process on your system deletes the directory between the time that you call `Directory.CreateDirectory()`, and when you call `Directory.Exist()`? By the way, I know of no instance when `Directory.CreateDirectory()` can return `null`. If that method fails, it will throw an exception. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In addition, `Directory.Exists` will return `false` if any error occurs while attempting to determine if the directory exists. This can be a file permissions error, a disk error, etc. Is it possible that your disk drive is throwing intermittent errors? When the error occurs, have you checked to see (using Windows Explorer, for example) whether the directory actually got created?

Comment: @JimMischel Folders do not get deleted. As for permission the shared folder have `Full Control` rights to `Everyone`. Since we are testing a concept we wanted to get rid of any security issues that would have slowed down. Hence why there is no anti virus install on that computer and the firewall is totally off.

Comment: @JimMischel Actually that's not totally true. Folders gets deleted by us manually after the code fails. When the test app fails we check all the errors and it's due to the error mention is the main post. So out of 100 folders created 2-3 could have failed. Then when that happen we delete ALL the folder manually. After than we have a couple things to reconfigure and then we restart the code that will repeat a long list of folder creation and might or might not fail. There is at least a good 5 min between the time we delete manually the folders and the time we restart the application

Comment: I can't say for certain that there is no bug in `Directory.Exists`, but I consider it highly unlikely, considering how widely it's used. Can you post the *actual* code you're running? Without that, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: @JimMischel I would also expect that there is no bug in `Directory.Exists`. This is the actual code except `@"\\TestComputer\data\folder1\"` is a string variable in the real code and in the `Directory.Exist` if statement if it true it call the file creation passing the path. The real application process create the folder, then read from database for the folder given and create files and save them in that folder. File creation is around 35,000 lines of code so way to long for stack overflow.

Comment: @JimMischel i've updated with the exact real code. When doing test we replace the `Console.Writeline` with writing to a text file instead.